# Move Actions on Google project to different Google email account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, google-iam

I see no way to move my Actions on Google project to a different Google account. I test developed with my personal Gmail and would like to switch it to my work Gmail.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this through the Google Cloud Console of your project. You can get there from the Action Console by selecting the settings gear and then Permissions.

[image]

You'll be brought to the IAM page in the Cloud Console for the project. You'll see that at least one of the permissions should designate you as the owner of the project.

Select the Add button at the top of the screen.

[image]

A new screen will appear on the right.

Enter the email address for the user, click on the "select a role" drop down, then select "Project" and then "Owner" when it appears.

Click the save button (hidden on this screen shot).

[image]

You'll notice that the new user has been added to the list, but there is a triangle next to their role. This indicates they've been invited to accept the role, but have not yet done so.

[image]

Once you do so from that account, you can depermit the other you (or just make it something less powerful than an owner, in case you still wanted to do some testing from that account).

Comment: Well that was about as perfect a tutorial as I could have hoped for. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Glad it helps! If it has helped, accepting and/or upvoting the answer is always appreciated.